# Is there a way to make angular run all the validations of an input instead of stoping when the first validation fails?

Tags: validation, angularjs

I'm having problems trying to make angular run all the validations of an input at once.
Here is a jsfiddle example of my problem http://jsfiddle.net/carpasse/GDDE2/

if you type 1 character on the email input you get this *"The minimum lenght is 3."* error message

and is not until you type 2 more characters than you get the other error message *"This is not a valid email."*

Does anybody know how to make angular show both error messages at the same time??

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2):

You problem is not that all the validators are not being run - they are!

Remember that the way these validations work is by passing the view values through a pipeline of transformation functions, which can also specify the validity of the value.

The problem is that the min length validator passes undefined down the pipeline if it is not valid and that the email validator says that undefined is a valid email address!

Try creating your own validation directive that says that undefined is not a valid email address and you will find both errors are showing: http://jsfiddle.net/eKfj3/

Comment: Feel free to tick my answer then!